# springframework multiple form in one view page

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I want to have two page views and two controllers.

*profile/update.jsp*

```
form:form id="updateform" commandName="profile" method="post" action="/profile/update/${id}"
```

*account/update.jsp*

```
form:form id="updateform" commandName="account" method="post" action="/account/update/${id}"
```

Now I want to merge them into one page view.
I should add profile and account in `profile/update.jsp`, and then submit them with one button.

How can I do that? 
Please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One form can handle only one set of data. The best solution is to create a complex bean with two entites:

```
public class FormData {
    private Account account;
    private Profile profile;

    ....
}
```

have a form:

```
<spring:url value="/handler" var="handler" />
<spring:form commandName="formData" action="${handler}" method="POST">
    <form:input path="account.id" />
    <form:input path="profile.name" />

    ...
</spring:form>
```

and a controller method:

```
@RequestMapping("handler")
public update(@ModelAttribute("formData") FormData formData){
    ...
}
```